# Apache 2.4 query string with regex

Tags: regex, apache, query-string

Ok...trying to get a leg up on the new way of writing SSI in 2.4

Any of the SSI gurus out there that can help....I would really appreciate it.

I have this code that works with SSILegacyExprParser on

```
http://path-to-webpage?dynContent=AboutUs

<!--#set var="dynContent" value="" -->
<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = /dynContent=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/" -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="$1" -->
<!--#else -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="default" -->
<!--#endif -->

<!--#echo var="dynContent" -->
```

**The expected Response is AboutUs** otherwise it is **default**

I have tried to re-write this line to make it work in Apache 2.4 without the SSILegacyExprParser like this....

```
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="" -->
<!--#if expr="(%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /dynContent=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)" -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="$0" -->
<!--#else -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="default" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

This works partially.  **I get a Response back as dynContent=AboutUs**

I really need it to give back AboutUs otherwise fallback to default

Any idea how I can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...this took a lot of research and some luck.....mostly luck :-)

I got this to work....I understand the old using regex PRE Apache 2.4 but I don't understand the regex after Apache 2.4.....but I did get this to work.
Here is the code I used.

```
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="" --> 
<!--#if expr="v('QUERY_STRING') =~ /(dynContent=)(.*)/ && $2 =~ /(.*)/" -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="$0" -->
<!--#else -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="default" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

I can now use it in the page as well as a variable for an include web page

```
<!--#echo var="dynContent" -->
<!--#include virtual="/path-to-page/${dynContent}.shtml" -->
```

If someone can explain this to me...please do....I would like to try and understand it.

Comment: The explanation is that due to bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57448 only $0 is available, and $0 is the entire matched string of the last regex, so the fragment "&& $2 =~ /(.*)" chains another regex where $0 becomes the entire matched string (that matches $2), and so you can "smuggle" out ONE regex ref as $0